# Arch Linux: connecting to a auth server without a GUI

Tags: networking, arch-linux, terminal

I have no GUI, so I have to use wpa_cli to connect to WiFi. This seems to be a issue with the auth server that my school uses.

I followed some different forms, but they don't seem to work. My WiFi connection only redirects form gstatic.com/generate_204. Then it generates a unique URL that displays the login page, due to the unique URL, I can't curl it to login for the terminal. Do you have any idea what I should do now?

I'm changing GUIs right now, but I need access to internet to download a new one.

Comment: did you try with `links` or `w3m`? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications/Internet#Console

Comment: I'm going to try with lynx